# Multi line chart does not render lines colors

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, flask

I am developping a web application using flask that takes data to plot it into a multi line graph. I have been successful on creating the necessary graph using three different javascript libraries (chart.js, apexcharts.js and highcharts.js) but I always ran into the same problem: the lines of the graphs stayed black while the markers and the tooltips show the colors that the lines should be.

The three different js libraries were obtained using npm for node.js and linking them using the *url_for* tag from Flask but also using cdn links for both js libraries and associated css.
I am really surprise by the problem.
I am running windows11, flask 2.2.3 and node 16.16.0.
Any helps is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to to fix the problem myself, it was another library interfering with the plotting library that I was using.